# Running shell script on instance startup

Tags: linux, amazon-ec2, amazon-web-services, glassfish-3

I'm trying to run a bash script when my EC2 instances start up. All I want to do is start up GlassFish when the server starts. The command I'm trying to run is:

```
sudo /glassfish3/bin/asadmin start-domain
```

Which works when I enter it manually.

I have tried adding this command in a couple places with no luck:

- at the end of /etc/rc.local
- at the end of /etc/rc.d/rc.local
- created my own script in /etc/init.d/

I have given every script 777 permissions.

Anyone have any ideas on what I'm doing wrong?

Comment: did you check your logs? nothing of interest?

Comment: (If running Debian or Ubuntu, incidentally, it is most orderly that you use the `update-rc.d` command to install scripts in */etc/init.d,* rather than doing it by hand.)

Comment: @jcomeau_ictx Where would the information be logged?

Comment: If @jcomeau_ictx is away from his keyboard, I will answer.  The logs are in */var/log/.*  On my system, the specific log is */var/log/daemon.log.*

Comment: thanks thb! I was busy with something else.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Unless oddly configured, `sudo` wants authentication when run.  It is normally meant to be run interactively.

Assuming that the script */glassfish3/bin/asadmin* is owned by *root,* you can set its file permissions to 6755.  This does what you probably meant `sudo` to do.  Of course, it can also be dangerous and may be a security risk.

(@jcomeau_ictx is right, incidentally.  You should check logs as he suggests.)

*Update for the benefit of archival:*  The above answer fortunately seems to have solved the OP's immediate problem, so we'll leave it at that.  However, since this answer will remain archived and others may look it up later, I should add more to it.

One *can* change the file permissions of any executable to 6755, but such is not always a good practice.  The effect of such permissions is (a) to let anyone run the executable with (b) the full privileges of the executable's owner.  Sometimes, this is exactly what you want, but see:  in the OP's case, `/glassfish3/bin/asadmin` with such permissions can now be called by anybody, with any arguments, with full root privileges.  If that is not what you want, then you must take some additional care.

Several ways of taking additional care are possible.  One is as follows.

1. Leave the executable with file permissions 755.
2. Write and compile a small wrapper, a program which uses `execv()` of *unistd.h* to launch the executable.
3. If practicable, do not let the wrapper take any arguments; otherwise, let its arguments be as restricted and inflexible as they can be.  Let the wrapper strictly control the arguments passed to the executable.
4. Let the wrapper be owned by *root,* but use `chown` to assign it a suitable group whose membership includes no users.  You may prefer to start a new group for this purpose but, if you scan the `/etc/group` file on your system, you are not unlikely to find an already existing group that suits.  For reference, you can list commands already belonging to special-purpose groups on your system by `ls -l /bin /usr/bin | grep -vE '^([^[:space:]]+[[:space:]]+){2}(root[[:space:]]+){2}'` or the like.
5. Give the wrapper file permissions 6754, thus making it nonexecutable except to the group in question.
6. Admit the calling script to the group, and give the calling script file permissions 2755.

If the calling script already belongs to a group, you can probably just use the same group throughout.

Several variations of the technique are possible, and it is unlikely that you will use exactly the one listed above, but if you read the manpage and/or info entry on the `chown` command and learn the details of file permissions, and if you experiment a little, you should be able to craft a solution that works for you without posing a security risk.

Comment: Changing the permissions to 6755 and removing the sudo worked. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Most probably it's JAVA_HOME issue, try using `sudo -i`, here is my working init script:

```
#!/bin/bash
# description: Glassfish Start Stop Restart
# processname: glassfish
# chkconfig: - 95 80

DOMAIN=domain555

GF_HOME=/opt/glassfish3
DOMAIN_DIR=/home/glassfish/domains
RUN_AS=glassfish

CMD_START="$GF_HOME/bin/asadmin start-domain --domaindir $DOMAIN_DIR"
CMD_STOP="$GF_HOME/bin/asadmin stop-domain --domaindir $DOMAIN_DIR"

function start() {
    sudo -u $RUN_AS -i $CMD_START $DOMAIN
}

function stop() {
    sudo -u $RUN_AS -i $CMD_STOP $DOMAIN
}

case $1 in
start)
    start;
;;
stop)
    stop;
;;
restart)
    stop;
    start;
;;
esac
exit 0
```

JAVA_HOME and PATH should be set in user's `.bashrc` or `.bash_profile`